# Constantly seeing a Textmate pop up message

Tags: macos, textmate, popups

Every time I boot my Mac I see this Textmate popup:

[screenshot of mac screenshot http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/popup-message.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/popup-message.jpg)

What is it and how do I kill it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a [growl](http://growl.info/) message. You can disable it in the system preferences.

Comment: @Pickledegg: You’re welcome (slight delay :P)!